# Azure pipeline - install module from artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am creating a pipeline on Azure devOps to deploy an angular application. Inside the project dependencies there is a library published on the artifact of another project (under the same organization). How to configure my yaml file so that only that library is installed from the artifact registry?

This is my yaml file

```html
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 14.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 14.x

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install angular-cli'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install -g @angular/cli@12.1.1'


- **TASK TO INSTALL MY LIBRARY FROM ARTIFACT**
 

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'create build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'

   - ...task to deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Artifact feed containing your required npm packages as upstream sources for the current project Artifact feed. To add upstream sources to your feed you can refer to [Configure upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#add-a-feed-in-your-organization-as-an-upstream-source).

Then you can add the packages you need to the dependencies of your package.json. And use npm task to install the packages.